# Блоки div при использовании MDL заезжают на меню nav

Tags: html, css, material-design

Как сделать что бы при использовании MDL блоки div распологались под меню сайта?

```
<div class="content-grid mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">

    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">

    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обернула в блоки под меню в `mdl-layout__content`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="content-grid mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
      
      
      <div class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
            mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
            mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
            mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так же обернул блоки подменю, ничего не изменилось. Посмотрев почему же у вас работает, а у меня нет обнаружил что эти блоки под меню сидят в блоке.mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header. То есть они относятся к фиксированному header'у? Есть какой либо другой способ?

Comment: Забавно, что всё работает без обертки для блоков под меню mdl-layout__content, если блоки под меню обернуты в вышеупомянутый mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header.

Comment: "сидят в блоке.mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header. То есть они относятся к фиксированному header'у" - как я поняла `mdl-layout--fixed-header.` - означает блок С фиксированной шапкой - значит нужно сделать в верху отступ на высоту меню. Но не означает саму фиксированную шапку. Без него все блоки, которые идут за шапкой будут залезать под нее, не будут видны. Другого способа нет.

Comment: По поводу второго, что и без `mdl-layout__content работает. Да работает, но это не совсем правильная структура, если уж использовать фреймворк, то правильно.